# Error : Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Mul'

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I defined a method below that is supposed to take 5 integer/float values as input, and one list object (the `lst` parameter) and return only the positive solutions for `r` in the equation `F`. The formula for F should return a list where each element is multiplied/subtracted using the equation given.

I got the error `Error : Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Mul'` mentioned above. What am I missing?

```
from sympy import *
from math import pi
class solarheating:

    def circular_rr(T0,T,lst,m,Cp,Eg):

        r = var('r')
        F = T0+pi*r**2*Eg/(m*Cp)*lst-T
        r = solve(F,r)

        return r[1]

    lst = [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0,1.25]   
    a = circular_rr(20,15,lst,.24,4.2,.928)
    print(a)
```

Comment: What happens if your change the `self.r = ...` line to `self.r = [solve(f, self.r) for f in F]`?

Comment: Don't edit your question to turn it into an entirely new question, even if the questions are about the same task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the instance of the object (or `self`) on which the code is being called to the method. Since there was no `self`, you were getting the non-int error, because T0 became `self`, `T` became `T0`, and then your `lst` was being used as `T`. Since you cannot subtract a int from a list, this produced an error.

Here's the corrected code.

```
from sympy import *
from math import pi

class solar heating:

    def circular_rr(self,T0,T,lst,m,Cp,Eg):
        r = var('r')
        F = T0+pi*r**2*Eg/(m*Cp)*lst-T
        r = solve(F,r)    
        return r[1]

lst = [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0,1.25]   
my_instance = solarheating()
a = my_instance.circular_rr(20,15,lst,.24,4.2,.928)
print(a)
```

The reason you need to use `self` is because Python does not use the @syntax to refer to instance attributes. The method is called on the instance you pass in the `self` attribute. You don't actually write instance methods in Python; what you write is class methods which (must) take an instance as a first parameter. And therefore, you’ll have to place the instance parameter somewhere explicitly.

Edit: 
Besides the obvious `self` error I've described above, you're multiplying a float by a list. That's what's causing the `can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Mul'` error.

If you want to multiply each item in the list by the float, your corrected method code will be:

```
    def circular_rr(self,T0,T,lst,m,Cp,Eg):
        r = var('r')
        temp_val = T0+pi*r**2*Eg/(m*Cp)
        F = [x*temp_val-T for x in lst]
        r = solve(F,r)    
        return r[1]
```

Comment: Should there be a self somewhere in the function as well? Like maybe self.T0 and self.Eg or something like that? I am still getting the same error when I run your code.

Comment: I added in a description for the type error in the edit above.

Comment: I believe I want to multiply each item in the list by the float. So I have a list of 6 values for lst and as such I should get 6 values r. So in the end I want a list of 6 r values.

Comment: @ZachThomas check the answer above. I corrected it to answer you question. You should also edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: I now am getting an empty list as my output. I updated my code and issue above. I am thinking that maybe it is because I am not setting r as an empty list to begin with and not appending it?

Comment: What you return from the solve() method, I can't comment on since we don't have that code. But since this code solved your initial error, consider marking the response as the answer?