# Why am I getting an empty list as the answer?

Tags: python, sympy

I am supposed to be printing out all values for r (which should be a list of 5 values) but for some reason I am getting an empty list [ ] as the answer. All of the inputs to the function are single values except for the lst variable, which is a list of 5 values. Any idea on why I am getting an empty list? All of the code I am using can be seen below.

```
from math import pi
from sympy import solve


class SolarHeating:        
    def waterheated(self, T0, T, lst, Cp, Eg, r):
        self.m = var('m')
        self.T0 = T0
        self.T = T
        self.lst = lst
        self.Cp = Cp
        self.Eg = Eg
        self.r = r

        A = pi * self.r**2
        Qt = self.Eg * A
        F = [(self.T - self.T0) * self.m * self.Cp / Qt - x for x in self.lst]
        self.m = solve(F, self.m)

        return self.m


lst = [0, .25, .5, .75, 1.0]
a = SolarHeating()   
m = a.waterheated(20, 40, lst, 4.2, .928, .128) 
print(m)
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/39067978/3901060 ?

Comment: @Zach: the complete lack of whitespace makes your code extremely non-readable. Also, the `solarToolbox` module is not used in your code, so drop it.

Comment: @Alberto, what do you mean lack of whitespace? Should I have more spaces in between lines of code?

Comment: @ZachThomas hemeansthatprogrammingisstilllikewritinginthatwhileitsreadablewithoutspacesitismoredifficultandawasteofenergy

Comment: @donkopotamus Ah, that makes sense. So have spaces in between my variables in my function for example?

Comment: @donkopotamus: LOL

Comment: @ZachThomas: in your code sample, mostly spaces after commas; in general, please read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @ZachThomas: I took the liberty of reformatting your code: mostly whitespace stuff, but also one assignment per line (two is okay, three is acceptable, more is unreadable), avoid `*` imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ...
    F = [(self.T-self.T0)*self.m*self.Cp/Qt-x for x in self.lst]
    self.m = solve(F,self.m)
    return self.m
```

This is most probably a math problem, not a code problem. Print the value of `F` and check that it really has a solution that `solve()` should return.

Comment: I don't know what the reason for the downvote is: printing `F` reveals that the OP is trying to solve an inconsistent linear system --- one that does not have a solution. Upvoted.

Comment: He could try sympy.solveset instead; it eclipses solve in most cases, per sympy's docs.

Comment: @Messa I changed the function to return F instead of m and I got a list of 5 expressions so I do believe it is an issue with the solve command. So I think it may be the solve command. I will try solveset

Comment: @ZachThomas: I repeat: your linear system has no solutions!

Comment: @Alberto Garcia-Raboso: It does have solutions. When I print out F I get [1758.57744147455*m, 1758.57744147455*m - 0.25, 1758.57744147455*m - 0.5, 1758.57744147455*m - 0.75, 1758.57744147455*m - 1.0], so all I need to do is solve for m there and I will have five different values for m as lst changes.

Comment: Maybe you want `self.m = [solve(eq, self.m) for eq in F]`. Because `solve(F, self.m)` solves one linear system with five expressions, not five linear systems with one expression each.

Comment: As @Messa says: your five equations with one unknown have no common solution, but if you want to solve each equation separately, you of course have them --- they are different problems, and your code is trying to solve the first case.

Comment: @Alberto yes I am trying to solve each equation separately

Comment: @Messa It worked! That makes a lot of sense, perfect